# Set visibility of css div after predetirmned time after document loads

Tags: jquery, html, delay, visibility, document-ready

Simply, I want my page to wait for 3-4 seconds then make everything in my main div visible.

I know I can set the visibility of the div ahead of time (to hidden), and then add a script that changes the visibility to visible after the page loads.

I'm pretty new to jquery/javascript so I'm not certain how to toggle that switch nor how to make it wait for a specific time after the document loads.

I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

some sort of sleep or delay
$("#dropshadow").notsurewhattodofromhere

});
```

So I have the very basic completely unfunctional flow of what I want, but all the java i keep trying to plug in there from what i'm seeing about delays doesn't seem to do anything at all, and i'm not sure how to target the visibility of the div with the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally ended up working for what I wanted to do.

Thanks for all the help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dropshadow").hide();

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#dropshadow").fadeIn(1000)
    }, 1500 );

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout()`,

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $("#dropshadow").show();
},3000); // 3 second delay
```

Comment: ////////
<script type="text/javascript"><br />
 setTimeout(function(){
   $("#dropshadow").show();
},3000); // 3 second delay

</script>

\\\\\\\\

that's what i used... it doesn't do anything

do i need to hide it with a script first?

i tried setting it to hidden in css but .show() doesn't seem to be switching it to visible in the css

would

$("#dropshadow").hide()

fit in there somehow in front of the show script?

so basically it would set it to hidden with jquery and then 3 seconds later set it to show?

Comment: @WesleyWeaver you need to put `setTimeout` inside `document.ready`

Comment: and just to clarify... i did try putting the hide script above the timeout script... it didn't work... so either im doing it wrong or............. i don't know enough to come up with an or

Comment: and wouldn't adding that to the document.ready ?object? make it not take effect until after the page has loaded?

Comment: @WesleyWeaver No, page load is a different thing, that will run when DOM is ready..

Answer (score 1):

Try `setTimeout()` method

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 setTimeout(function(){

//do what ever you want here
 }, 3000 );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout( function(){}, timeInMilliseconds);
```